# There are two subfolders A and B under a large folder. How to import the .py file from B into A?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the structure of my folder like,

```
my_proj(large folder)
-__init__.py
-dosomething(A)
 --__init__.py
 --test.py
-calculate(B)
 --__init__.py
 --add_num.py
```

While

```
#in add_num.py
def my_add_num(a, b):
    return a + b
#in __init__.py
from .add_num import my_add_num
```

I want to use `my_add_num` in `dosomething/test.py`, so I tried to use three methods,but both shows error, how to correct it?

```
# from ..calculate import my_add_num
#ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

#from calculate.add_two_num import my_add_two_num
#No module named 'calculate'

from my_proj.calculate import my_add_num
# No module named 'my_proj'

print(my_add_num(100,300))
```